# CLion Tab key not inserting proper spacing

Tags: clion

I'm using CLion for writing some C++ code, but the editor seems to be misbehaving.

First of all, it keeps inserting spaces instead of tabs, even after "converting the file to tabs" and setting both "Default (IDE)", "Project specific" settings to use tabs. (I did this for all languages and for the "General" tab).

On top of that, in the following code fragment, pressing tab jumps between various values, instead of actually inserting a tab-character.

```
Math::Vector triangleVertices [3] = {   Math::Vector(-0.5f,  -0.5f,  0.0f),
                                        Math::Vector(0.5f,   -0.5f,  0.0f),
                                        Math::Vector(0.0f,   0.5,    0.0f)};
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this behaviour, or what settings I need to adjust to stop this?

The about tab shows the following build/versions:

```
CLion 2017.2.1
Build #CL-172.3544.40, built on August 2, 2017
```

Edit: Grammar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the tab key is key-mapped for indentation along with switching to *next parameter*, which it is supposed to determine intelligently.

You can disable/change this behaviour by navigating to `Preferences > Keymap > Next Parameter`.

Regarding spaces, goto `Preferences > Editor > Code Style > {Language} > Tabs and Indents` and choose what suits you best.